# Why do I get numerical issues warning during scaling of an array using sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scaling

I scale an numpy array like this using sklearn:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

# Normalizing
if normalize: 
    for b in range(n_batches):
        for i in range(n_samples):
            for c in range(n_colors):
                temp_interp[b, i, :, :, c] = scale(temp_interp[b, i, :, :, c])
```

I face this user warning error:

```
Numerical issues were encountered when scaling the data and might not be solved. The standard deviation of the data is probably very close to 0.
```

Why do I get this error? How can I fix this? How much it's important when I train a CNN using scaled data with this error warning?

Comment: The error is self explanatory. The standard deviation of a column is very low, so scaling is leading to values close to infinity.

Comment: Thanks. But that's the nature of my data. What's solution in this case?

Comment: you can try the min-max scaler.